# Why does Windows 10 time service not sync immediately?

Tags: windows-10, ntp

After rebooting my PC (Win 10 Pro, 64-bit), I found that my time was off by slightly more than 1s. I have an application that requires the time to be set more accurately than that, so I went into Settings and clicked "Sync Now". It indicated that it had successfully synchronized, but the clock was still off by about 1s. I then went into the Control Panel - Date and Time - Internet Time and made sure the box was checked to synchronize with an Internet server and the server I had entered (north-america.pool.ntp.org) was selected. Clicked "Update Now", and again it indicated that it successfully synchronized. The clock was still off by about 1s. I went through some suggestions I found online about stopping/starting the time service and re-registering the service/DLL, and it made no difference.

When I unlocked the PC the next morning, its time was accurate to within 0.02s. My question is why did my attempts to manually sync the clock not do so (despite the fact that it was telling me that it did), but after just sitting idle for several hours it DID eventually correctly sync? Should I switch to a 3rd party NTP client?

Comment: If you need to be more accurate than 1 second, then you may need a computer that has a very accurate clock.  https://www.pcworld.com/article/2891892/why-computers-still-struggle-to-tell-the-time.html

Comment: Why are you using a non-standard time server?

Comment: [According to ntp.org](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm#Q-ACCURATE-CLOCK) typical accuracy over the Internet is 5-100ms. I installed Meinberg NTP, and my clock is staying within about 30ms now, which is acceptable for my use. I think w32time is just unreliable.